# Unable to connect to AWS Athena from AWS Java SDK, but AWS CLI connection works

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to access Athena tables from Java using AWS Java SDK.

I am connected to the corporate VPN and also am behind proxy ( I don't know, if it makes difference, hence mentioned both )

I am able to connect to Athena from AWS CLI from the same set-up.

I am using the [example from here](https://contactsunny.medium.com/how-to-query-athena-from-a-spring-boot-application-93a93c013c85) to create a simple java test app.

I have added below properties in the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "acces_key_value";
    String AWS_SECRET_KEY = "secret_key_value";
    String AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = "session_token_value";

    System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId", AWS_ACCESS_KEY);
    System.setProperty("aws.secretKey", AWS_SECRET_KEY);
    System.setProperty("aws.sessionToken", AWS_SESSION_TOKEN);
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}
```

When I run the app, I get the below error

```
Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId)
```

This is the full stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:763) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.contactsunny.poc.SpringBootAmazonAthenaPOC.App.main(App.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId).
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:111) ~[sdk-core-2.20.162.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.internal.SystemSettingsCredentialsProvider.resolveCredentials(SystemSettingsCredentialsProvider.java:58) ~[auth-2.20.162.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.MetricUtils.measureDuration(MetricUtils.java:54) ~[sdk-core-2.20.162.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.internal.authcontext.AwsCredentialsAuthorizationStrategy.resolveCredentials(AwsCredentialsAuthorizationStrategy.java:100) ~[aws-core-2.20.162.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.internal.authcontext.AwsCredentialsAuthorizationStrategy.addCredentialsToExecutionAttributes(AwsCredentialsAuthorizationStrategy.java:77) ~[aws-core-2.20.162.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.internal.AwsExecutionContextBuilder.invokeInterceptorsAndCreateExecutionContext(AwsExecutionContextBuilder.java:125) ~[aws-core-2.20.162.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.invokeInterceptorsAndCreateExecutionContext(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:69) ~[aws-core-2.20.162.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:78) ~[sdk-core-2.20.162.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:179) ~[sdk-core-2.20.162.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:76) ~[sdk-core-2.20.162.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45) ~[sdk-core-2.20.162.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:56) ~[aws-core-2.20.162.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.DefaultAthenaClient.startQueryExecution(DefaultAthenaClient.java:3330) ~[athena-2.20.162.jar:na]
    at com.contactsunny.poc.SpringBootAmazonAthenaPOC.App.submitAthenaQuery(App.java:81) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.contactsunny.poc.SpringBootAmazonAthenaPOC.App.run(App.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:779) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

What else do I need do to get the Java SDK app to connect to Athena to work?

Comment: Somehow, the system property `aws.accessKeyId` is blank by the time Athena client tries to read it. What happens if you set a breakpoint on `submitAthenaQuery` and look at the system properties at that point?

Comment: Are you using the V2 RdsDataClient object that queries Amazon Aurora Serverless data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using AWS Java SDK V2 but you referenced a 3rd party example that uses V1.

The issue you are seeing is your client cannot find your cred keys. Make sure that you specify your creds as specified in the **Java V2 Developer Guide** here:

[Default credentials provider chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-chain.html)

Now for your question about using a VPN. That can certainly impact connecting to Aurora database as it can impact your IP address when setting up Inbound Rules. I have come across that many times in the past. If you set your inbound Rules using your IP withot VPN and then connect to VPN, you IP changes.

For information about setting up security group inbound rules, see [Controlling Access with Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html).

Comment: Thank you.  I corrected the code to use the V2 client.  And also disconnected from the VPN ( but connected to wi-fi ) and I was able to get the result.   One question, if I may - how do I find the IP address of my Mac when I am connected to VPN and when I am not ?  'ipconfig getifaddr en0` gives me the router IP.  I should find the public IP in both the above set-ups, right?  So I can see the inbound rules ( with help of someone in the org ), please let me know how do I get those IPs if you know.  Appreciate your help

Comment: A little tip. Use http://checkip.amazonaws.com/.